# Do cat owners have a lower chance of developing allergies?

Tags: zoology, immune-system, allergies

The following is from http://blog.petspyjamas.com/getty-dog-owners-vs-cat-owners-unbelievable-facts/9/:

> **9. Cat owners have a lower chance of developing allergies**
>
> When cats enthusiastically rub themselves against your legs, it isn’t
>   just out of affection or a desire for food. Those clever cats are also
>   helping to boost your immune system, and are particularly great for
>   triggering allergy immunity in babies. No wonder they were worshipped
>   as gods in ancient Egypt!

Is it true?

Comment: It seems that there are two claims here - that exposure to cats is good for the immune system, and that cats are aware of this effect, and intentionally try to produce it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The evidence is somewhat mixed. Maybe. In summary, there is conflicting evidence. None of the evidence here is particularly strong. I conclude that cat exposure is neither associated with a strong benefits nor detriments, or we might expect to see more consistent results.

None of these studies are sufficient to show causality - merely suggestive correlation.

---

---

### Mild evidence that cats are good

- HESSELMAR, Åberg, Åberg, ERIKSSON and BJÖRKSTÉN (1999), [Does early exposure to cat or dog protect against later allergy development?](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1046/j.1365-2222.1999.00534.x/abstract?deniedAccessCustomisedMessage=&userIsAuthenticated=false). Clinical & Experimental Allergy, 29: 611–617. doi: 10.1046/j.1365-2222.1999.00534.x

This was only a survey but it found cat exposure was negatively correlated to allergies.

> Children exposed to pets during the first year of life had a lower frequency of allergic rhinitis at 7–9 years of age and of asthma at 12–13 years. Children exposed to cat during the first year of life were less often SPT positive to cat at 12–13 years.

---

---

### Evidence that cats are mildly evil

- Syed Hasan Arshad, David Wallace Hide, [Effect of environmental factors on the development of allergic disorders in infancy](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009167499290077F), Journal of Allergy and Clinical Immunology, Volume 90, Issue 2, August 1992, Pages 235-241, ISSN 0091-6749, DOI 10.1016/0091-6749(92)90077-F.

> Exposure to animal dander did not influence the prevalence of clinical disorder, but positive SPT reaction to cat dander was more prevalent in infants who were exposed to cats and/or dogs (p = 0.04)

So cat exposure isn't associated with serious allergy problems, but is associated with subclinical ones.

---

---

### Evidence that cats are mild

- [Infant feeding, wheezing, and allergy: a prospective study.](http://adc.bmj.com/content/68/6/724.short)
  M L Burr, E S Limb, M J Maguire, L Amarah, B A Eldridge, J C Layzell, T G Merrett
  Arch Dis Child 1993;68:6 724-728 doi:10.1136/adc.68.6.724

This was a study focussed on cow's milk, but as an aside:

> Allergic disease was not associated with exposure to tobacco smoke, house dust mite antigen, or cats.

So cat exposure is UNcorrelated with allergies.

- Susanne Lau, Sabina Illi, Christine Sommerfeld, Bodo Niggemann, Renate Bergmann, Erika von Mutius, Ulrich Wahn, the Multicentre Allergy Study Group, [Early exposure to house-dust mite and cat allergens and development of childhood asthma: a cohort study](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0140673600028427), The Lancet, Volume 356, Issue 9239, 21 October 2000, Pages 1392-1397, ISSN 0140-6736, DOI: 10.1016/S0140-6736(00)02842-7.

> However, no relation between early indoor allergen exposure and the prevalence of asthma, wheeze, and bronchial hyper-responsiveness was seen.

So, cat exposure is UNcorrelated with allergies.

Comment: If someone can find a peer-reviewed meta-analysis, I would vote it up over this answer.

Comment: @Oddthinking I found [this review](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12582308) from 2003, but it comes to much the same conclusion.

Comment: @Geobits: Nice find. I would still suggest writing an answer based on that, because it is still more recent than my cites, their literature review was more systematic, and they have more expertise so their conclusions are more definitive.